# How to display Yes/No Attribute on Catalog Page

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, custom-attributes

Typically I can use the following code to display something like an image or a button on a product page when the value of the IF statement is "1" or "true:"

```
<?php if ($_product->getData('SOME-ATTRIBUTE')): ?>
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('This Item Has Been Discontinued') ?>" class="button btn-cart discontinued"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Discontinued') ?></span></span></button>
<?php endif; ?>
```

However, this does not work on catalog listing pages. The IF statement is ignored. How should this be written to work on catalog listing pages?

Comment: In which phtml you made the above change?

Comment: ../catalog/product/list.phtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure below are satisfied in your case:

1. The attribute is set to **“Used in Product Listing” => Yes** in **Magento Admin -> Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes**
2. The attribute is added to the corresponding attribute set in **Magento Admin -> Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attribute set**
3. The value of the attribute is set for atleaset one product (For testing purpose, otherwise your statement will be ignored all the time)

If you confirmed all the above, do a re indexing if notified in admin.

Comment: I edited the question, because I don't believe your answer matches what I am seeking.

Comment: updated the answer, I have tested with a new attribute and it worked for me.

Comment: Since all the other attributes that I use like this one for conditional purposes with IF statements are only used in the product page, they did not need to be set to “Used in Product Listing” => Yes. So I did not set this newest attribute up as "Yes." Changing that worked. Thank you.